# RowIndex out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, databound

I'm having some trouble with my code.
I'm trying to show a different picture for each case.
But the code seems to be flawed, I'm pretty new to C# and ASP.net so I get lost pretty easily.
Here's the portion of the code that crashes:

```
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string Class = (e.Row.FindControl("txtClass") as TextBox).Text;
        HtmlControl htmctrl = e.Row.FindControl("imgid") as HtmlControl;
        switch (Class)
        {
            case "A1":
                {
                    string Logo = @"C:\Users\Rudra\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\Box_Blue.png";
                    htmctrl.Attributes.Add("src", Logo);
                    break;
                }
            case "A2":
                {
                    string Logo = @"C:\Users\Rudra\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\Box_Green.png";
                    htmctrl.Attributes.Add("src", Logo);
                    break;
                }
            case "A3":
                {
                    string Logo = @"C:\Users\Rudra\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\Box_Red.png";
                    htmctrl.Attributes.Add("src", Logo);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    string Logo = @"C:\Users\Rudra\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\not-found.png";
                    htmctrl.Attributes.Add("src", Logo);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

The crash Happens on the first line `GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];`. `RowIndex` is not recognised (doesn't show up on intellisense). 
If you can see where I went wrong, why this crashes and how to fix it I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: You can comment out this line `GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];` you have taken it necessarily, You  aren't using instance variable `row` anywhere  in `OnRowDataBound` except assigning it with row index.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not convert

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

Instead you can directly use it as

```
GridViewRow row = e.Row;
```